# SelectedItem of a ListBox always returns null, even if an item is selected (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory, listbox, selecteditem

Im writing a small GUI Application with PowerShell and having the issue that the selectedItem-value is always null, even though an item is selected.

The items in the ListBox are directly written into it from an Active Directory.

here's my code:

```
$employeeIDs = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "Abteilungs*"} -Property employeeid | Select-Object name, employeeid | Sort-Object name

foreach($employee in $employeeIDs)
{
    $listBoxBenutzer.Items.Add($employee.name)
}


$buttonSave.Add_Click(
{
    $listitem = $listBoxBenutzer.SelectedItem

    if($listitem -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host "Is empty"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $listitem
    }
})
```

[Its always writing "Is Empty"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyF9y.png)

The code of the GUI is:

```
#MAINFORM

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize = "450, 230"
$form.controls.Add($groupBoxBenutzer)

#GROUPBOXES

$groupBoxBenutzer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBoxBenutzer.Text = "Benutzer"
$groupBoxBenutzer.Size = "315, 200"
$groupBoxBenutzer.Location = "15, 15"

#TEXTBOXES

$textboxEmployeeID = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxEmployeeID.Location = "230, 40"
$textboxEmployeeID.Size = "70, 30"
$groupBoxBenutzer.controls.Add($textboxEmployeeID)

#LISTBOXES

$listBoxBenutzer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBoxBenutzer.Location = "15, 40"
$listBoxBenutzer.Size = "200, 150"
$groupBoxBenutzer.controls.Add($listBoxBenutzer)

#BUTTONS

$buttonSave = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonSave.Location = "230, 70"
$buttonSave.Size = "70, 25"
$buttonSave.Text = "Speichern"
$groupBoxBenutzer.controls.Add($buttonSave)

#LABELS

$labelName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelName.Location = "15, 20"
$labelName.Text = "Mitarbeiter Name"
$groupBoxBenutzer.controls.Add($labelName)

$labelNumber = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelNumber.Location = "230, 20"
$labelNumber.Size = "90, 20"
$labelNumber.Text = "Personal-Nr."
$groupBoxBenutzer.controls.Add($labelNumber)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

For me it really doesn't make any sense that the value is null.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: for me it works **IF** I put the line `$form.controls.Add($groupBoxBenutzer)` just above the `$form.ShowDialog()`, because now you are adding the groupbox to the form before it is defined.. Also, better use `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($listitem)` instead of `if($listitem -eq $null)` and remember that variable `$listitem` is just a variable **local** to the $buttonSave Click scriptblock

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you for your advice. In my case the listboxitem still is null. However the textbox is now working. i'm still trying to figure out the listbox issue.

Comment: As said, `$listitem` is a variable that only exists locally in your $buttonSave Click scriptblock. Define it somewhere on top of the script and inside the Click scriptblock address it using `$script:listitem`

Comment: I figured it out. The local variable had nothing to do with it, it was the generated elements of the GUI. I've put them all to the bottom and now it works. Nonetheless thanks!